# Trying to do page navigation ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am beginner to ASP.NET Core, I'm trying to do page navigation. Navigation page working incorrect, if I go to the next page, then the transition to the next page does not occur

Model:

```
public class Product
    {
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
    }
```

view model PagingInfo.cs:

```
public class PagingInfo
    {
        public int PageNumber { get; private set; }
        public int TotalPages { get; private set; }

        public PagingInfo(int count, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
        {
            PageNumber = pageNumber;
            TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)pageSize);
        }

        public bool HasPreviousPage
        {
            get
            {
                return (PageNumber > 1);
            }
        }

        public bool HasNextPage
        {
            get
            {
                return (PageNumber < TotalPages);
            }}}
```

ProductsListViewModel.cs:

```
public class ProductsListViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public PageViewModel PageViewModel { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller, I think I made a mistake somewhere here:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> List(string category, int productPage = 1)
        {
            IQueryable<Product> source = _repository.Products.Where(p => category == null || p.Category == category)
                .OrderBy(p => p.ProductID);
            var count = await source.CountAsync();
            var items = await source.Skip((productPage - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();

            PagingInfo pagingInfo = new PagingInfo(count, productPage, pageSize);
            ProductsListViewModel productsListView = new ProductsListViewModel
            {
                PagingInfo = pagingInfo,
                Products = items
            };

            return View(productsListView);}
```

View List.cshtml:

```
@model ProductsListViewModel
@foreach (var p in Model.Products)
{
    @await Html.PartialAsync("ProductSummary", p);
}

    @if (Model.PagingInfo.HasPreviousPage)
{
    <a asp-action="List"
        asp-route-page="@(Model.PagingInfo.PageNumber - 1)"
        class="btn btn-default btn">
         <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i>
        Back
    </a>
}
@if (Model.PagingInfo.HasNextPage)
{
    <a asp-action="List"
        asp-route-page="@(Model.PagingInfo.PageNumber + 1)"
        class="btn btn-default btn">
         <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
        Move
    </a>
}
```

Comment: You have `asp-route-page`, but your variable is called `productPage`, so shouldn't it be `asp-route-productPage`? Or change your variable name to `page`?

Comment: Thanks! My bad! Now, page navigation works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past, I've implemented pagination manually. Since I've discovered [X.PagedList](https://github.com/dncuug/X.PagedList), I use it to automatically tare take of slicing the items into pages and creating previous/next buttons. It's also highly customizable.

You can start with the NuGet package `X.PagedList.Mvc.Core` and the examples listed on their page

Answer (score 0):

I strongly advise you to use XPagedList lib and here is perfect example of its usage

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/paging-in-asp-net-mvc-4-using-pagelist/

I know some people hate when you paste links from external sites just to get a vote, but i'm sorry not gonna spend 15 minutes copy pasting here :)

Good luck with it,
Kind regards, js